# how to perform upsert when using ADF for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-data-factory

I need help here, so my task is to perform upsert in the ADF pipeline for PostgreSQL. The way that I tried to do is with simple copy activity but is not allowing me to do write behavior for the postgre db. So the way that I'm tring now is with stored procedure activity, but the activity is not allowing me to create a linked service to the postgre db. If not with stored procedure then how is possible to do upsert? Anyone who can help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a data flow activity to your pipeline canvas and in there add your Postgres source, then use an Alter Row activity to define your upsert rules.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks again for your answer, but there's no difference, or at least i don't know how to do it properly! 
Basically, the idea is to achieve the following thing: when adding a record that is duplicate, the procedure or the activity needs to drop and not allow adding. And when the record is new to be inserted as new. I'm not sure if the upsert is the right thing or the individual insert/delete condition. Any suggestions how is the proper way in this case? Thanks

Comment: Inside the data flow, add an Alter Row transformation. Set a policy for "Upsert" and then turn on Upserts on the Postgres sink.